# Report on cases closed in the last hour

Tags: formula-field

my customer would like to be able to report on (and hence have a dashboard component showing the) number of cases closed by their customer service operators in the last hour.

The way I thought of doing this is the following:

- create a checkbox formula field on Case, that gets populated only if the time the case was closed is in the range timenow() and timenow()-1h (meaning that this checkbox would be dinamically flagged based on the current time and the time the case was closed);
- create a report and filter using said field;
- create a dashboard component showing the count based on the above report.

I got stuck at the first step.
I know that when using datetime fields in formulae the times are converted to GMT, and my formula takes that into account; however, it is not working.

What I have is the following:

```
IF(AND((TIMENOW()) < (TIMEVALUE(ClosedDate+0.0417)), (TIMEVALUE(ClosedDate+0.0417)) <= (TIMENOW() + 0.0417)), true, false)
```

which is quite simple actually:

- IF the closedDate (plus one hour to take into account the time is converted to GMT) is greater that timenow()-1h (which is written as only timenow() because it is in GMT and hence it is already moved back by one hour)
- AND if closedDate is less than timenow() (written as timenow()+1h because it is in GMT) then mark the checkbox as true.

If nothing of the above applies, flag the checkbox as false.

In theory, this should work. Closing the case correctly populates the closedDate field, and I have tested that using ClosedDate+0.0417 correctly shows my time of closure.
I have also tested that timenow() and timenow()+0.0417 show the times I am interested in.

Why is the formula field not working then?
I did not manage to find a way to have this working.

Also, feel free to comment giving me any other working way in which you would report on cases closed in the last hour! I do not have my mind set on this method, it was just the first thing that I though of that might have actually worked!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how picky the business are with the report view, you can create a matrix Report which will be row grouped by the standard `CloseDate` field and column grouped by a custom formula field representing the hour of the day the Case was closed.

Custom Number formula field to generate a representation of the hour the Case was closed:

```
Value(MID(TEXT(ClosedDate - (0.0417*4)), 12, 2))
```

The business can add filters for specific dates in the past aswell as using `Today` to get a count of Closed Cases.

[image]